# Batch - Removing lines containing a pipe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have several text files where each line starts with a group code, and each data item is separated by pipe characters. There is a specific group that will sometimes have data, and sometimes have no data, and will therefore only have the group code and pipes. I am trying to remove these groups with no data, while keeping the ones that do have data.

For example, two lines in my file would look like:

```
A01|ABC|123|XYZ|
A05|123456789||
A05|||
A01|DEF|456|UVW|
A05|987654321||
A05|||
A08|SOMEDATA|
```

I want it to look like

```
A01|ABC|123|XYZ|
A05|123456789||
A01|DEF|456|UVW|
A05|987654321||
A08|SOMEDATA|
```

I have tried to use findstr, as below:

```
type MYFILE.txt | findstr /v "A05|||" > MYFILE.txt
```

however this is deleting everything from the file, rather than just lines containing A05|||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using another file:

```
FindStr/RV "^A05||" MyFile.txt>AnotherFile.txt
```

Then if needs be **del**ete **Myfile.txt** & **ren**ame **AnotherFile.txt MyFile.txt**

Comment: I don't think there is, I think the intent is only to find lines beginning with the A05 field and followed by an empty second field. The third field content is immaterial to them.

Comment: I realised now that the provided sample data does not contain a fixed number of fields per line...

Comment: You can delete and rename using a single MOVE command: `move AnotherFile.txt MyFile.txt >nul` I like to name the temporary file the same as the original with a `.new` extension. In your case I would use `MyFile.txt.new`.

Comment: Great. +1 :-)   I've deleted my out-of-date comments that are no longer needed. Feel free to do the same with yours.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but there are two issues in your command line:

```
type MYFILE.txt | findstr /v "A05|||" > MYFILE.txt
```

1. The redirection `> MYFILE.txt` is applied to the entire command line, so when redirection is prepared, the (new) empty file `MYFILE.txt` is created first, then the command line is executed. To avoid that, redirect the output to another file and move this onto the original one afterwards.
2. The search string matches only lines beginning with `A05`, but not something like `A06|||`. To match such lines also, change the search string to `|||$` (`$` anchors the match to the end). In case the number of fields may vary, you could use this: `^[^|]*|*$` (meaning any number of characters other than `|` as group code, followed by any number of adjacent `|`; the `^` at the beginning anchors the match to the beginning of the line; together with the `$` that anchors the match to the end, it enforces the entire line to match the given pattern).

Hence the corrected command line looks like this:

```
type "MYFILE.txt" | findstr /V "|||$" > "MYFILE.txt.tmp" & move /Y "MYFILE.txt.tmp" "MYFILE.txt" > nul
```

Or, with the alternative search string for a variable number of fields:

```
type "MYFILE.txt" | findstr /V "^[^|]*|*$" > "MYFILE.txt.tmp" & move /Y "MYFILE.txt.tmp" "MYFILE.txt" > nul
```

The quotation marks around the file path/name are just inserted to yield a more general syntax, which does not fail even in case white-spaces or some other poisonous characters occur.

Comment: NO! - Adding parentheses does not solve anything. You still have a race condition where you assume the left side completes before the right side has a chance to execute the redirection. A file of moderate size will get truncated using your suggestion. It is impossible to reliably overwrite the original file correctly without using a two step process and a temporary file (assuming you stick with native batch)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I just tested it with the sample data from the question, so I drew a wrong conclusion, but creating a similar file with about 350 lines was truncated. So this means piping and redirecting is not done at once, but with the data divided into blocks of data, is that true?

Comment: The pipe is asynchronous, and the right side most definitely does not wait for the entire left side to complete before it begins. I don't know exactly how it is buffered. But I don't think it is a fixed size. I know it is not line based, as a TEE program on the right will properly display a SET /P prompt before the user types a response and presses [Enter].

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your explanations! I updated my answer accordingly...